# Onsen CSS Components Conflicting with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, onsen-ui

I was wondering if it is possible to use OnsenUI CSS Components (http://components.onsenui.io) within a jQuery mobile web app.

I am only trying to use the CSS Components, not the entire OnsenUI, for this project, and so far the CSS styles seem to be conflicting.

Is there a simple way to reduce conflicts? Or is the best way to rename all Onsen CSS Classes to make sure they are individual?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not full-proof, but you can use data-role="none" to tell jQM to leave elements alone. This will allow OnsenUI to apply the CSS without conflict, e.g.:

```
<label class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" class="switch__input" data-role="none" />
     <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
</label>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fxv4u962/1/)**